# How can I take image from the amazon s3 bucket to my local system using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I have been working with Ruby on Rails for a couple of months. My requirement is to take the images in the Amazon S3 to local system. I was able to get the objects, but not getting the image.

I have written the following code.

```
s3_details = YAML.load(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml"))    
s3 = AWS::S3.new(
  :access_key_id      => s3_details[Rails.env]['s3_access_key'],
  :secret_access_key  => s3_details[Rails.env]['s3_secret'] 
)
bucket = s3.buckets['bucket_name'] 
bucket.objects
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What does `bucket.objects` returns?

Comment: <AWS::S3::ObjectCollection>

Comment: If your goal is just getting images to your local, you may consider to use  http://s3tools.org/s3cmd

Comment: I mean `bucket.objects.inspect`. We can see it is an array. Just need to figure if it is an array of images.

Comment: Then, if it is an array of images, you can loop through them and get the files using the url.

Comment: I am getting the array, and image url also. but how can I get that image. please tell me.

Comment: you mean like `<img src="that image url" />` or do you need to download it with an `HTTPClient` ?

Comment: I need to download only.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at [fog](https://github.com/fog/fog).
It has the big advantage of supporting several providers. So if tomorrow, you want to use something else than S3, you can very easily, with the same API.

And you can read a file very easily too.

```
connection = Fog::Storage.new({
  provider:              'AWS',
  aws_access_key_id:     '',
  aws_secret_access_key: ''
})
directory = connection.directories.new(key: 'bucket_name')


directory.files.each do |s3_file|
  File.open(s3_file.key, 'w') do |local_file|
    local_file.write(s3_file.body)
  end
end
```

The above example will connect to the bucket `bucket_name`, and download all files found there.